# How can I draw this plot?

Tags: graphics, visualization

How can I draw a plot like this one? I want to be able to specify the x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis ticks and the number of bars in the plot.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a _Mathematica_ generated plot. Where did you find it? Can you supply a link?

Comment: I got it from google.

Comment: Please post the link anyway. Many students had come in the past with homework plots to be reproduced. Not your case, surely

Comment: A hint `f[x_, y_, n_] := 
  Total@Flatten@
    Table[UnitBox[(x - a)/100, (y - b)/100], {a, 200, n 200, 200}, {b,
       200, n 200, 200}];`

Comment: "I got it from google" - perhaps there's some data on the same page that might be useful...

Comment: This is the link: [VisualizationPlot](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-ap.hipchat.com/29784/193642/n150nq3dw2gs3l9/RodsSliceVisualization.jpg)

Comment: @belisarius i didn't understand your answer. can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Google reference isn't forthcoming, it's probably easier to fake it like this:

```
i = Blur[ 
     Image[Graphics[{
        Black, 
        Table[Rectangle[{x, y}, 20 + {x, y}], 
         {x, 0, 100, 35}, 
         {y, 0, 100, 35}]}, 
       PlotRangePadding -> 15, 
       Background -> White], 
      ImageSize -> 100],
     1];
xticks = Transpose[{Range[0, 100, 20], Range[0, 1000, 200]}];
yticks = Transpose[{Range[0, 100, 20], Range[0, 1000, 200]}];
zticks = Transpose[{Range[0, 1, .2], Range[0, 25, 5]}];
ListPlot3D[ImageData[i] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> 1 - z, 
   Mesh -> 20, 
   Ticks -> {xticks, yticks, zticks}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0.1]
```

[image: fake image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got another problem not only with this Plot, its with all the try that i made for the same plot. When i Deploy the code in CDFDeploy, its working fine but i couldn't rotate the plot.

Comment: I have found myself the answer for CDFDeploy problem. I have resolved the problem using Manipulate.

Comment: I have customized the number of bars i want on the plot, But i couldn't customize the height of each bar, Because in your code you get the data from image which range between 0 and 1. I want the height of some bar to be 20 and some to be 25 and so on.

Comment: @niren I think you should probably first of all specify/supply the 'data' that you want to plot, then people here on this site can help you plot it in different ways. I just used an image because there was no data. To change the heights of the bars in my example, I would make some of the squares less black ...:) Perhaps you really want to construct a 3D object from `Cuboids`? If you put more effort into your question, any answers you get will be more relevant and useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something similar to the given example using [**Histogram3D**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram3D.html), which comes with many options.

You need to specify the data you have in hand in your question. If you really need a flat top, as you show in your example, you could use the function `UniformDistribution` as the input for `Histogram3D`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but Histogram3D doesn't give me the plot the way i want.

Comment: What's the problem with `Histogram3D`? Do you want a gap between the colummns?

Answer (score 2):

You really need to specify better what you want. In case you want to draw 3D rectangular columns with some gap in between, the following code would do the work:

```
    max = 10;
    step = max;
    factor = 2*max;

    DiscretePlot3D[ factor * PDF[ 
     UniformDistribution[{-max, max}], {x, y} ], 
     {x, -max, max, step}, {y,-max, max, step},
     ExtentSize -> max/2 ]
```

Comment: Hello there! I just wanted to point out that you can easily edit your previous answer by clicking the [edit link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/20174/edit) and add this (and other updates) to it instead of serially posting answers  :)